What is this Japanese gangster/supernatural film?
I'm trying to identify a film I watched about 6-7 years ago. I'm not sure when it was made, but it didn't seem like it would be earlier than the 90s.
It was probably Japanese (though possibly Korean), and it involved some kind of mystical power source which could only be accessed at a specific time once every hundred years, possibly also only by people of a particular bloodline?
Two groups were both attempting to obtain this power, and there was a lot of action set in a forest, with at least one of the group being mobsters who turned up with guns in a car. There was lot of martial-arts style fighting, some gun fights, and possibly also some kind of creatures (e.g. zombies or vampires?) around.
I remember the brief final scene was set at the next 100-year opportunity, in a city, with the person who'd obtained the power last time facing off against a gang.
Does anyone recognise this?

The film is Versus (2000) by director Ryuhei Kitamura, an independent yakuza-zombie cult film popular among Western fans of Japanese cinema. 
Escaped prisoners fleeing into a forest turn on each other, then clash with the yakuza (Japanese mobsters). The prisoners learn that the forest is one of 666 supernatural portals located on Earth, each bestowing new power to whoever opens them. In this forest, the portal has the effect of summoning the dead. Absurd fights ensue as living kill living, then living kill dead, using everything from melee and gun combat to supernatural attacks with repeated zombie resurrections. 
It's been 12 years or so since I saw this film and had forgotten the ending, but regarding "the next 100-year opportunity, in a city", Wikipedia confirms: 

99 years later, Earth lays in ruin. The reincarnation of The Man travels through the remains of a city, and eventually confronts... 

UPDATE:
At the time of writing, Youtube user "Gorizard8" is hosting the entire 120-minute film (dubbed in English) on his channel. 
